# как Сохранить значения , выбранные select после отправки формы ? laravel

Tags: laravel

для инпута понятно, а для селект как?

```html
<input name="mname" id="mname" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{old('mname')}}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот еще вариант

```
<select name="city_id">
        <option>Выберите город</option>
        @foreach ($cities as $city)
          <option value="{{$city->id}}"{{ $city->id == old('city_id') ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{$city->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Этот вариант точно лучше

Answer (score 2):

Думаю что можно и лучше но на скорую руку так вроде:

```
<select name="city_id">
    @if (old('city_id'))
      @php
          $city = $cities->where('id', old('city_id'))->first();
      @endphp
      <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->name}}</option>
    @else
      <option>Выберите город</option>
    @endif
    @foreach ($cities as $city)
      <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```